# Get all columns from a table in Monetdb

Tags: monetdb

I have to study a table on monetdb that probably has many columns.
When I do

> SELECT * from cat.data limit 1;

I get

```
1 tuple !5600 columns dropped!
```

Which I interpret as not getting all the columns from the console.

I am using **mclient** to connect to the database.

I tried withe `DESC`, `DESCRIBE` - didnt work. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. See mclient --help
It is possible to extend the width of your output to see more columns.

Alternatively, within the mclient console use the \d tablename command

Answer (score 0):

You need to use \w-1 command before executing your query.

```
sql>\w-1
sql>SELECT * from cat.data limit 1 ;
```

This will show all the columns in the terminal. The text will be wrapped.